# UpdateSelection from Vercel rooks is not working

Tags: reactjs, vercel

Does anyone know how *useSelectableList* works?

`https://rooks.vercel.app/docs/useSelectableList`

Whenever I try to run `updateSelection` it is not working.

This is my implementation:

```
const useDateFilter = (initIndex = 2) => {
  const [selection, { toggleSelection, updateSelection }] = useSelectableList(
    dateOptions,
    initIndex
  )

  const switchSelection = (index) => toggleSelection({ index })()

  const updateDates = (index, values) => {
    const value = {
      name: dateOptions[index].name,
      description: dateOptions[index].description,
      start: values?.start,
      end: values?.end,
    }
    updateSelection({ value })
  }

  return [
    { index: selection[0], ...selection[1] },
    switchSelection,
    dateOptions,
    updateDates,
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Finally, I consume it in that way:

```
const [dateFilter, switchDate, , updateDates] = useDateFilter()
```

I realize that only `switchDate` changes the state variable 'dateFilter' but  `updateSelection` doesn't.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I cannot do the same using useSelect either. In both cases, I only can modify the selected index.